# Сравнение многомерного массива по 2 элементам

Tags: javascript, массивы, сравнение

Здравствуйте,

Есть данный код

```js
var arr = [
  [50, 50, '3'],
  [1, 1, '6'],
  [50, 50, '9']
];

for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
  for (let n = 0; n < arr.length; n++) {
    if (arr[j][n] == arr[j++][n++]) {
      arr[j].splice(2, 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Необходимо сравнивать по двум элементам. То есть если первые элементы совпадают сравнивать второй элемент и если они тоже совпадают удалять 3 элемент у совпавших массивов.

на выходе должен получиться массив:

```
arr = [ 
  [50, 50],
  [1,1,'6'],
  [50,50]
];
```

Comment: первые элементы это только числа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не такая простая задача как может показаться. По-моему, без двойного прохода тут не обойтись.

Для начала вам требуется пройтись по элементам и собрать информацию о повторениях.

После пройтись для удаления ненужных элементов.

В итоге получилось что-то вроде этого (это можно оптимизировать):

```js
var arr = [
  [50,50,'3'],
  [1,1,'6'],
  [50,50,'9']
];

var counter = [];

for(let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
  if (arr[j][0] == arr[j][1]) {
    counter.push(arr[j][0]);
  }
}

for(let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
  if (getCountOfElement(arr[j][0]) > 1){
    arr[j].splice(2, arr[j].length - 2);
  }
}

function getCountOfElement(value) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < counter.length; ++i){
        if(counter[i] == value)
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: попробуй писать более развернутые ответы, а не просто кусок кода

Comment: Проблема, начинается если в массиве встречается более 2 типов совпадающих элементов. Он начинает сплайсить все подряд

Comment: @DanilShauba попробуйте сейчас. И добавьте ваш тестовый массив в вопрос.

Comment: @AGS17 да, работает, дальше уже адаптирую, спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись одним проходом, для этого можно воспользоваться методом [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) и хранить группы в дополнительном объекте. Если группа присутствует в объекте, значит из массива нужно удалить элемент, если нет - нет

Например так:

```js
var arr = [
  [50, 50, '3'],
  [1, 1, '6'],
  [50, 50, '9']
];

var res = arr.map(function(el) {
  var group = el.slice(0, 2);
  if (this[group] === true) {
    return group;
  }

  if (this[group]) {
    this[group].splice(2, 1);
    this[group] = true;
    return group;
  }
  return this[group] = el;

}, {})

console.log(res);
```